# NoMethodError: undefined method title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, nameerror

I am new in using ruby on rails and rspec

I am getting this problem when i try to execute the rspec tests for Mymodel Controller.

Mymodel is working as expected when i access the page via the browser... But fails when i execute the rspec tests!

```
class MymodelController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @model = Mymodel.find(:first, :conditions => { :title => "Model-Title" } );
  end
end
```

Then my rspec tests look like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MymodelController do

  describe "GET 'show'" do
    it "assigns @model as Mymodel" do
      get 'show'
      expect(assigns(:model)).to be_a Mymodel
    end

    it "assigns model should have 'Model-Title' as title" do
      get 'show'
      expect(assigns(:model).title).to eq "Model-Title" 
    end

  end

end
```

Any clues ?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are the Errors encountered:

```
Failures: 

1) MymodelsController GET 'show' assigns model should have 'Model-Title' as title 
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:model).title).to eq("Model-Title") 
NoMethodError: undefined method title' for nil:NilClass  
#./spec/controllers/mymodels_controller_spec.rb:15:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' The
```

The line 15 is `expect(assigns(:model).title).to eq("Model-Title")`

```
2) MymodelsController GET 'show' assigns @model as mymodel
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:model)).to be_a(Mymodel)
   expected nil to be a kind of Mymodel(id: integer, title: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
 # ./spec/controllers/mymodels_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The code line corrsponding is : `expect(assigns(:model)).to be_a(Mymodel)`

Comment: Is this an exact copy/paste of your test?

Comment: Yes! I tried to add parenthesis as well to the `eq`and `be_a`but i still have problems... This time it says `undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Can you show your backtrace and identify the corresponding lines from your source code?

Comment: MymodelsController is located in mymodels_controller.rb file under `app/controllers/` directory. For the naming, i was just trying to see if it will be a problem, but i get the same errors... I am indeed following the plural convention

Comment: Ok, well that error makes perfect sense in that if `@model` is `nil` in the controller, that's the error you'll get. Your question indicated `NameError` and had a different error message, however.

Comment: I see your updated question with a different error message for the first example, which also makes sense, but the question title and rest of the question body still refer to the `NameError`. Does that error not apply to the code you've shown?

Comment: It does! I have 2 tests, and those are the 2 errors that i get after the rspec execution ( I put the complete backtrace in the question )

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. I don't see `NameError` or `undefined local  variable of method 'model` in either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created any `Mymodel` instances in your test, so presumably the `Mymodel.find` is returning `nil`, which explains the errors you've shown in your edit (for the first example) and your comment (for the second example).

The `NameError` you've shown in your title and in your question body is most likely from an attempt to use `assigns(model)`, which would failed in that fashion.

Comment: You're right ! I was missing the creation of the corresponding subject. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could the `NameError` have been from a run where you tried `assigns(model)` instead of `assigns(:model)`?

Comment: Yes, this is possible! I did try `assigns(model)` to see if it was going to fix the problem.

Comment: In the future, you might want to double check that the output and code that you've shared go together. For my part, I've learned that I should question both the code _and_ the output, rather than just the code, as I did in my initial comment.

Comment: I agree! This happened because i was trying some stuff from my side while/after i posted the question... I'll edit the question title so it corresponds to the current output to avoid confusion.